# Scoped transaction started in stored procedure is incomplete and it was rolled back (snowflake)

Tags: sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```python
class Database:
   cls.db_conn = create_engine(
   URL(user='xxx', password='xxx', account='xxx',
   database='xxx', schema='xxx', warehouse='xxx',
   role_name='xxx', ), pool_size=4,
    max_overflow=8, pool_pre_ping=True)

   Session = sessionmaker(bind=cls.db_conn, autocommit=True)
   cls.session_maker = scoped_session(Session)


def get_session(self):
    session = Database.session_maker()
    return session

def execute_query(self, query, values=None, with_result=True):
       session = None
       result = "No result"
       try:
           session = self.get_session()
           output = session.execute(query, values)
           if with_result:
               result = output.fetchall()
           session.commit()
           return result
       except Exception as e:
           session.rollback()
           raise e
       finally:
           self.close_session(session)

  def change(self, id, name, status, data):
           query = "call extraction_process(:b_id, :na, :status_1, :data_source)"
           values = {'b_id': id, 'na': name, 'status_1': status, 'data_source': data}
           execute_query(query, values)
```

when select query is used to fetch some results it works fine but to insert any values using query its throwing stored procedure execution error. hope this is the right way to create session for snowflake if not help me new to this .Tried many ways to fix it. Is it because of session creation , connection or any other ? someone pl's help me.

this is the error i'm getting

```
Exception while executing this query call expraction_process(:batch_id, :job_name, :job_status, :data_source_id): (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 090232 (25000): Stored procedure execution error: Scoped transaction started in stored procedure is incomplete and it was rolled back.
[SQL: call expraction_process(%(batch_id)s, %(job_name)s, %(job_status)s, %(data_source_id)s, )]
[parameters: {'batch_id': 1, 'job_name': 'access', 'job_status': 'processid', 'data_source_id': 1, : 'h'}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1900, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snowflake/connector/cursor.py", line 789, in execute
    Error.errorhandler_wrapper(self.connection, self, error_class, errvalue)
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py", line 273, in errorhandler_wrapper
    handed_over = Error.hand_to_other_handler(
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py", line 328, in hand_to_other_handler
    cursor.errorhandler(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py", line 207, in default_errorhandler
    raise error_class(
snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 090232 (25000): Stored procedure execution error: Scoped transaction started in stored procedure is incomplete and it was rolled back.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/application/modules/db_module/database.py", line 63, in execute_query
    output = session.execute(query, values)
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1712, in execute
    result = conn._execute_20(statement, params or {}, execution_options)
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1705, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 333, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1572, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1943, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2124, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1900, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snowflake/connector/cursor.py", line 789, in execute
    Error.errorhandler_wrapper(self.connection, self, error_class, errvalue)
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py", line 273, in errorhandler_wrapper
    handed_over = Error.hand_to_other_handler(
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py", line 328, in hand_to_other_handler
    cursor.errorhandler(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py", line 207, in default_errorhandler
    raise error_class(
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 090232 (25000): Stored procedure execution error: Scoped transaction started in stored procedure is incomplete and it was rolled back.
[SQL: call expraction_process(%(batch_id)s, %(job_name)s, %(job_status)s, %(data_source_id)s, )]
[parameters: {'batch_id': 1, 'job_name': 'access', 'job_status': 'processid', 'data_source_id': 1, : 'h'}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1900, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snowflake/connector/cursor.py", line 789, in execute
    Error.errorhandler_wrapper(self.connection, self, error_class, errvalue)
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py", line 273, in errorhandler_wrapper
    handed_over = Error.hand_to_other_handler(
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py", line 328, in hand_to_other_handler
    cursor.errorhandler(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py", line 207, in default_errorhandler
    raise error_class(snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 090232 (25000): Stored procedure execution error: Scoped transaction started in stored procedure is incomplete and it was rolled back.

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/test.py", line 10, in <module>
    print(ob.change(1,"access","processid",1,"h"))
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/application/modules/db_module/db_calls.py", line 14, in change
    self.database.execute_query(query, values)
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/application/modules/db_module/database.py", line 75, in execute_query
    raise e


File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/application/modules/db_module/database.py", line 63, in execute_query
    output = session.execute(query, values)
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 1712, in execute
    result = conn._execute_20(statement, params or {}, execution_options)
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1705, in _execute_20
    return meth(self, args_10style, kwargs_10style, execution_options)
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 333, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1572, in _execute_clauseelement
    ret = self._execute_context(
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1943, in _execute_context
    self._handle_dbapi_exception(
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2124, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_(
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 208, in raise_
    raise exception
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1900, in _execute_context
    self.dialect.do_execute(
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 732, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snowflake/connector/cursor.py", line 789, in execute
    Error.errorhandler_wrapper(self.connection, self, error_class, errvalue)
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py", line 273, in errorhandler_wrapper
    handed_over = Error.hand_to_other_handler(
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py", line 328, in hand_to_other_handler
    cursor.errorhandler(connection, cursor, error_class, error_value)
  File "/home/ONE/extraction-process-sevices1/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/snowflake/connector/errors.py", line 207, in default_errorhandler
    raise error_class(
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (snowflake.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 090232 (25000): Stored procedure execution error: Scoped transaction started in stored procedure is incomplete and it was rolled back.
[SQL: extraction_processbatch_id)s, %(job_name)s, %(job_status)s, %(source_id)s)]
[parameters: {'b_id': 1, 'na': 'access', 'status_1': 'processid', 'data_source': 1,}]
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)
```

Comment: I don't know Snowflake, but this reads to me like the problem is in the stored procedure, not in the app layer.